# String Comparison Java

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have a collection of lock combinations that is being outputed. I want to make sure that no combination is repeated. The combinations are not just ints. I converted them all to Strings for simplicity of the format. What is the line of code that allows me to loop and compare each string so that none are repeated? Any ideas? e.g 2D arrays

Thank you.

Comment: How are you storing the collection? Is it a subclass of `java.util.List`?

Comment: are the lock combinations input in real time or from file, etc.

Comment: If you want the simplest solution, try adding them to a `Set` (`HashSet` is probably better in this case). It may not be the quickest possible solution but it should be fast enough and very easy to implement.

Comment: How do you get to 2d arrays from Strings? Are you calling a `split`?

Comment: The collection is randomly generated at run time.

Comment: What is this collection stored in though? It can be an array, an `ArrayList`, a `HashMap`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to store your lock combinations in a set. This would make it much easier to ensure that they are unique.

This will be much faster too, since you do not need to compare every string with all of the other strings in your dataset...

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified that the number of lock combinations varies depending on user input. Can still store them in a set?

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate each combination as a List via [Arrays.asList(T... a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to keep their ordering and store those in a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to ensure uniqueness and constant time performance on [contains(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to determine if it's already present.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class UniqueLocks {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List lock1 = Arrays.asList("1", "22", "333");
        List lock2 = Arrays.asList("a", "bb", "ccc");
        List lock3 = Arrays.asList("eee", "bbb", "ccc");

        HashSet uniqueLocks = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(lock1, lock2, lock3));

        List duplicateLock = Arrays.asList("1", "22", "333");

        if (uniqueLocks.contains(duplicateLock)) {
            System.out.println("Lock [" + duplicateLock + "] already present.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language your planning to do this with but you can check to see if two strings have the same value in C# like so

```
String myString = "Hello World!"; 
String myString2 = "Hello World!"; 

if(myString.equals(myString2)) {
    //do something cause we have a match

}
```

if you have an array of strings you can just loop through them.

its very similar in other languages like java, vb.net.

EDIT: the java tag was added after I started writing my answer.. sorry

Hope this helps,